# Why do we need to use malloc() or any other Dynamic Memory for ARRAYS in C?

Tags: c, arrays, malloc

Consider these codes in **C**:

```
int n;  
scanf("\n%d ",&n);  
int arr[n];
```

and this.

```
int n;
scanf("\n%d ",&n);
int *p = (int *)malloc(n*sizeof(int));
```

Why do we need dynamic memory allocation for this in the first place?
and is the first code not Dynamic Memory Allocation as the array is created during runtime?

When should I use malloc()?

Comment: *For this*.. - for what? This program is not doing anything. And as a side note, *DMA* is more commonly known for being "Direct Memory Access".

Comment: Any good C textbook or tutorial will explain why dynamic memory allocation is needed.

Comment: For example, you need to use `malloc()` if the array needs to persist after the function returns.

Comment: The first version uses a relatively modern feature of C standard: variable length arrays, or VLAs for short. The original C standard from 1990 did not have VLAs, but the updated C standard in 1999 defined them. In the later updated C standard from 2011, support for VLAs was made optional. The advantage of VLAs is that you don't need to free them. The disadvantage of VLAs is that they might result in a stack overflow error that cannot be handled gracefully (within the confines of the C standard).

Comment: Arrays of variable length did not exist before C99. In many cases you can use one or the other to implement what you want to achieve. There are differences, so both have advantages and you would choose one or the other in different cases. (A question why you can choose between different tools is difficult to answer.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`int arr[n];` [allocates memory on the stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack-based_memory_allocation). It is [automatically allocated and then deallocated at the end of the block](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_variable). A pointer to stack memory cannot be safely returned from a function.

Consider this.

```
#include <stdio.h>

char *make_array() {
    int n;  
    scanf("%d",&n);

    // Memory for `arr` is allocated on the stack.
    char arr[n];

    // And then deallocated when the function exits.
    // A good compiler and editor will warn you if you try
    // to return it.
    return arr;
}

int main() {
    // This pointer is to memory which has already been freed. Other things
    // will overwrite it.
    char *arr = make_array();

    arr[0] = 'c';
    arr[1] = '\0';

    // This could be the letter c, but it's probably gibberish.
    puts(arr);
}
```

If you need memory to live beyond the life of the current function, you need to allocate it on the heap with `malloc` and manage it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

```
int n;  
scanf("\n%d ",&n);  
int arr[n];
```

where the `n` is a runtime-dynamic value (as it is in this case) was not supported in older versions of C, which required that the `n` be an integer constant expression.

Modern versions of C have lifted this limitation, allowing dynamically sized arrays (variable length arrays, or VLAs), but unlike the old fixed-sized arrays, VLAs have restrictions.

They aren't allowed to be jumped across (with `break`/`continue`/`goto`), they might not be be async-signal-safe, they will crash your program if they get too large, and they will often generate larger code than plain old local arrays.

Also, because they're local, you can't return a pointer to them to your caller.

The size limitations is one of their biggest restrictions. VLAs are carved out of the call stack, which is typically only a couple of kilo/mega-bytes large, and you get a typically undiagnosed crash if you exceed this limit.

`malloc`'d memory doesn't have such a limit, `malloc` failures are clearly reported via a returned `NULL`, and because `malloc`'d memory is global to the process, you can pass a pointer to it back to your caller.

`

Answer (score 0):

```
int n;  
scanf("\n%d ",&n);  
int arr[n];
```

If it works then that means you are using compiler that still interprets it as *"DMA"* the only difference here would be that it will get deallocated at the end of the scope but I don't think it's a good practice for C.

Comment: you mean after I have exited the program, the array is destroyed? and malloc isn't until we use free()?

Comment: No, array is destroyed at the end of the scope 
{your scope}

Comment: But if you leave some allocated memory your OS should deallocate it automatically after you exit your application but that's also a bad practice...

Comment: @AyushBasak memory allocated by `malloc` should be reclaimed by the operating system automatically when the process exits, but it is generally considered good practice to free such memory explicitly before exiting the process. A program should definitely not keep "forgetting" to free stale memory blocks while allocating replacement memory blocks in an ad hoc manner. That's a "memory leak".

Answer (score 0):

Just to be sure you understand:

When "functions call functions," their local variables are stored in an area of memory known as "the stack," so named because it works like a push-down LIFO stack.  When a function is entered, the stack grows.  When the function returns, it shrinks.  And if a function recursively calls *itself,* there's no confusion because each instance has its own area on the stack.

`malloc()` allocates memory "upon request" from a different area called "the heap," so named because it has no particular built-in organization.  These areas of memory are referenced *indirectly,* using "pointers," which are variables whose value is understood to be a memory address.

The "C" language conveniently allows you to use "array notation" when using pointers, just as it does with local variables that are allocated on the stack.